# Need help with my template

Tags: templates

I have this site here http://spillersmart.dk where it currently shows 3 videos in a row. I want it to show 5 videos instead, but can't figure out where in the code to change that. I've looked into the css-file, but without any luck :-(

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a **CSS** question, not a **WordPress** question.

Comment: Can you offer any clarification as to why this is a wordpress, and not a CSS question?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that you need to look at After your third video there is

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

That is forcing the 4th and 5th video onto a new line. Remove this.

You also need the containing box to be big enough to hold 5 video's in a row therefore in the css you need to chaneg the size of div class .contentbg, .contenttop, .contentbtm and .content as they are all set to a width of 660px.

I would also ask if you need to set the width on all these elements and arte they all needed? rthe less html and css you have the easier it tends to be to debug.